# Java Swing: Images not Displaying when run from jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

Swing application and it's Images are running fine in eclipse. but when i run from **jar** file, images not displaying. I tryed to load images in different way, but some time jar file not executing.

My image folder is inside of source folder.

I load my images with:

1.Running fine in eclipse, but not in jar

```
ImageIcon right = new ImageIcon("./chack img/Green Tick 1.PNG");
```

2.Running fine in eclipse, but jar file not executing.

```
ImageIcon wrong = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/chack img/Red Cross1.PNG"));
```

I tryed some other code also, still my issue not solved.

Comment: Are the files really named that? Jars are case sensitive, so use ".png" if that's the actual name.

Comment: See `learn more…` in [tag:embedded-resource].

Answer (score 1):

**Put your images in the src folder, along with your classes. Optional, but make a package that stores your images. Compiling a jar file will not keep any directories that are not a source directory.**

Also, remove all spaces from your folders and file names. This prevents confusion, and is likely part of your problem. No spacing is a good practice to follow in programming, and in most situations of naming folders and files.

Also, [kiheru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2471439/kiheru) is correct, you should not have capital letters in the file extensions, for the same reason you should not have spaces; It can cause confusion and it is a bad practice in most cases.

EDIT: [Simmilar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231256/java-file-path-when-running-from-as-jar?rq=1)